# QML application crashes; How to Debug?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

There is a crash in my QML application. Is there any way to debug it to find where it initiates?

Comment: I doubt the actual QML code will result in a debug, you will likely just get error in the console. Might be your C++ side of things, the QML stuff has been made pretty safe.

Comment: console.log() is the best you can get for now i guess..

Answer (score 4):

Yes, check the "Enable QML" check box in [Creator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.2/creator-debugging-qml.html) before debugging:

> In the Run Settings, Debugger Settings section, select the Enable QML check box to enable QML debugging.

As mentioned though, if you have any C++ code, then the problem likely lies there, and so you shouldn't need to enable QML debugging; just debug the code as usual.